# Need Clarification in update event

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

world_->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);

In update method, i do not know the functionality of the above code.

Can any one explain me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you’ve added the bodies to your world, usually we use "Box2D can do its magic on simulation – as long as you call its “Step” function periodically so it has processing time. in your "update" method:

```
int velocityIterations = 8;
int positionIterations = 1;
```

Instruct the world to perform a single step of simulation. It is generally best to keep the time step and iterations fixed.

```
world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
```

Once you have a world created as above, you can add bodies into it as we've been doing. To make anything interesting happen, we need to repeatedly call the Step function of the world to run the physics simulation.
check this one too. http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Box2D , http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/worlds